# CORS request blocked after enabling CORS in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

**Edit**
It the standard Firefox Developer tools the request is sent. However the response is empty not status code nothing. In Chrome I also get net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I am trying to sent a cross-domain AJAX request using Javascript. Before sending the request I JQuery I have enabled CORS like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            crossDomain:true,
        });
```

I tried to send a test request using Fiddler and in the response headers I have:

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
```

However I still can't get the following request working in Firefox and Chrome

```
   var data = {
      uid: uid,
      pwd: password,
      deviceid: deviceid,
      push: push
  };

  var settings = {
    type:"POST",
    data: data,
    success: onLoginSuccess,
    error: onLoginFailed
  };
  $.ajax(globals.getServiceURL() + "/login", settings);
```

In Firebug console I get:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
reading    the  remote resource at (request URL goes here). 
This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

How do I properly enable CORS?

Comment: what are the other response `Access-Control-*` response headers

Comment: also try to return the header `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS`

Comment: `crossDomain:true` does not enable CORS. It tells jQuery to not add the extra headers that it would add for a local Ajax request because the local request is expected to be redirected (with HTTP Location headers) to a different origin). This prevents a request that would otherwise be a simple request from turning into a complex request that would require a preflight OPTIONS request.

A browser either supports CORS or it does not. These days, the "does not" case almost never applies.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin,accept,content-type,content-length,uid,pwd,deviceid,devicetype,push,token,hash,id

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect? Pay particular attention to the request type (is it actually POST?).

Comment: That looks like an error message from Firefox. Have you tried another browser? Chrome tends to have better error messages when it comes to CORS failures.

Comment: You have to do it @ serverside.

Comment: If the response is blank in the developer tools, then that suggests something is going horribly wrong server side and its aborting.

Comment: @Quentin in the Firefox console I now get the same message like in Firebug; Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at (Service Location)

Answer (score -1):

Note that Access-Control-Allow-Methods doesn't support "*" value.
(http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#syntax)

Also, the "*" cannot be used for Access-Control-Allow-Origin that supports credentials.
(http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests)

Please follow the link to learn more about how to make CORS requests from JQuery.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-cors-from-jquery